# Issues Running simple JQuery with JSF1.2 and Rich Faces3.3.3

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I am using RichFaces3.3.3 with JSF1.2 and lately have tried to integrate JQuery with the JSF and RichFaces..

However my Jquery is not firing at all...Morever even a simple alert is not popping up...

Here's the code snippet:-(jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js" >
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery("input:radio[@name='frmCreate\\:Radio']").change(function() { 
                  alert("name");
});
});
</script>
```

I tried with a new script tag and loading the jquery.js file..Even that is not working.
I tried with two script tag one to load js and other as default..In third script tag I wrote the Jquery..That is also not working...
Tried using $j, that is also not working.

My JSF code:-

```
 <h:selectOneRadio id="Radio"  border="0" label="Region Name" value="#{Bean.Region}" required="true" styleClass="intro">
                                                   <f:selectItem id="india" itemValue="All India" itemLabel="All" />
                                                   <f:selectItem id="region" itemValue="Regional" itemLabel="Region" />

                                                  </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Can anyone please help me with this...What i intend to do is on radio clicked I will extract the value and compare with a static string..Based on the value I will show/hide JSF component..

However I am not able to run a simple jQuery on JSF...
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

RichFaces 3.3.x comes with jQuery integrated. You can make use of it via the `<rich:jQuery>` tag, here are some links about the tag:

- [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_jQuery.html)
- [RichFaces Live Examples](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jQuery.jsf?c=jQuery)
- [`<rich:jQuery>` tag reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/jQuery.html)

Comment: I tried with rich:jquery..Problem is I dont know how can I write complex jquery inside rich:jquery..I have already been through those links..The tutorial given is very basic...Using <rich:jquery> how can I extract the radio value and compare it with a string.After that I need to show/hide jsf component..Can all these things achievable using <rich:jquery>..If yes I would please request you to explain me how it can be done...

Comment: I agree, it's not a great tag. For complex jQuery interactions you can load the RichFaces-bundled jQuery with `<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>`. You can then select elements using the [RichFaces JavaScript helpers](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#JavascriptInteractions).

Comment: while using <a4j:loadScript> I get an exception.Refer to this link for the exception trace..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455710/a4jloadscript-for-loading-jquery-script-throwing-exception..My requirement as of now is only to disbale/enable components on click of radio buttons by extracting values.

Comment: Can you point out any error in the code pasted above.If I can run Jquery like this lot of problems will be solved...

Comment: Is the jQuery script definitely being loaded? Try typing `typeof jQuery` into the `console`.

Comment: I am not sure it is getting loaded or not...Because even a single alert is not coming..Infact that is my question...Why it cannot load and fire a JQuery....How can I print typeof Jquery in console..Which console are you talking about.

Comment: Sorry, should have said: can you run your code in Firefox with Firebug installed? Or Chrome? If you press F12 in these browsers you'll get a console into which you can type JS commands.

Comment: No the script itself is not getting loaded...M Sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now solved..
The way DOM gets created was the problem and using FireBug I Debugged the script and corrected the problems..
For escaping I used 3 \...FrmName\\:ComponentID